# Angularjs - assign variable in callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `controller as`-syntax and met a ridicilous circumstance

```
this.showAddressDetail = false;
this.searchPlace = function() {
    GoogleService.searchPlace($('#address')[0], function(place) {
        this.showAddressDetail = true;
    });
};
```

whenever the callback of GoogleService.searchPlace be triggered. I want to assign **true** to this.showAddressDetail. But in this case `this` is the callback function.

**So how to assign value to this.showAddressDetail?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the "main" `this` to another variable:

```
var vm = this;
vm.showAddressDetail = false;
vm.searchPlace = function() {
    GoogleService.searchPlace($('#address')[0], function(place) {
        vm.showAddressDetail = true;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `this-that` approach to save outer `this` context

```
var that = this;
that.showAddressDetail = false;
that.searchPlace = function() {
    GoogleService.searchPlace($('#address')[0], function(place) {
        that.showAddressDetail = true;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword by default refers to the owner of a function - not necessarily the place in code ([reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)).

To fix this simply store the controllers `this` in a local scope variable:

```
var vm = this;
vm.showAddressDetail = false;
vm.searchPlace = function() {
    GoogleService.searchPlace($('#address')[0], function(place) {
        vm.showAddressDetail = true;
    });
};
```

Common keywords for the local variable are `vm` (ViewModel), `that`, `_this`, `self`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to call a function with a specific value of `this` in case that function is not called as a constructor.

```
var fn =  function(place) {
    this.showAddressDetail = true;
};
var callback=fn.bind(this);
this.showAddressDetail = false;
this.searchPlace = function() {
    GoogleService.searchPlace($('#address')[0],callback);
};
```